# Set VoiceOver to ignore placeholder text in UITextField?

Tags: ios, accessibility

I have a UITextField for the user to enter their phone number. The placeholder text for the field is (XXX) XXX-XXXX. For sighted users, this works great, but with VoiceOver turned on, it sounds pretty bad to just read out all the X's.

I have accessibilityLabel set to "Phone Number" and accessibilityHint set to "Requires 10-digit phone number". Right now, VoiceOver will read the label, then placeholder text, then the hint. Is it possible to set VoiceOver to ignore the placeholder text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around this by removing the label and then changing the placeholder text when VoiceOver is turned on:

```
if UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning() {
    phoneNumberField.placeholder = "Phone Number"
}
```

Now, it will just read the placeholder text and then the accessibility hint. I feel like this is a bit of a hacky solution though. So, if there is a way to have VoiceOver ignore certain pieces of information, that would be more ideal.